# How do I know my controller was called, when unit testing with sinon?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, sinon, chai

Pretty new to Unit Testing in Angular. I've read loads about spies, stubs, and mocks but I am having a ton of trouble with execution of the basics:

- Is my controller properly receiving the services that I have passed to the constructor?
- Is a call to `initializePage` being made on instantiation?

---

Controller.spec (pretty sure the following is required)

```
    'use strict';
    describe('Controller: MainController', function() {

      // load the controller's module
      beforeEach(module('myApp'));

      var MainController, scope;

      // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
      beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        MainController = $controller('MainController', { $scope: scope });
      }));
```

Rest of spec:

```
it('should have called initializePage', function() {
        var spyInstance = sinon.spy(MainController, "initializePage");
        assert(spyInstance.called, "initializePage() was not called once");
      });
    });
```

I have been thinking that a spy is sufficient for this, but I'm not sure if `MainController` is even being executed. Currently `spyInstance` throws false. **Do I need a stub here instead? Why?**
Controller

```
class MainController {
  constructor($scope, $http, $state, Session) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$state = $state;
    this.Session = Session;
    this.initializePage();
}

initializePage() {
//blah blah
}
```

Thanks.

---

**Revision:**
main.controller.spec.js

```
describe('Controller: MainController', function() {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('scriybApp'));

  var mainControllerInstance, scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    mainControllerInstance = $controller('MainController', { $scope: scope });
  }));

  it('should test the controller is in order', function() {
    assert.isFunction(mainControllerInstance.$onInit, "$onInit() has not been defined");

    sinon.spy(mainControllerInstance, "$onInit");
    assert(mainControllerInstance.$onInit.called, "$onInit() called = false");
  });




});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller testing has some pitfalls in Angular. Primarily because it is not possible to spy on a constructor of a class that is available only as class instance (which the result of `$controller(...)` is). When `$controller(...)` is called, there's nothing to spy on, the constructor has been already called, end of the story.

For this purpose ES6/CommonJS modules should be utilized in addition to Angular modules to expose controller class and spy on prototype methods. Since ES6 is already used in project, it is

```
export class MainController { ... }
```

and

```
import { MainController } from '...';
...
scope = $rootScope.$new();
sinon.spy(MainController.prototype, 'initializePage');
mainControllerInstance = $controller('MainController', { $scope: scope });
assert(MainController.prototype.initializePage.called);
assert.strictEqual(mainControllerInstance.$scope, $scope);
...
```

But more importantly, `initializePage` reinvents the wheel. Its job is already handled by [`$onInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks) lifecycle hook in Angular 1.5 and higher. It is called on directive compilation automatically and can serve as a substitution to pre-link function.

`$onInit` isn't called on controller instantiation but it can be safely assumed that it will be in directive, thus there's no need to put spy on it. It is more test-friendly, the test becomes

```
class MainController {
  constructor($scope, $http, $state, Session) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.$state = $state;
    this.Session = Session;
  }

  $onInit() {
    //blah blah
  }
}
```

and

```
scope = $rootScope.$new();
mainControllerInstance = $controller('MainController', { $scope: scope });
assert.isFunction(mainControllerInstance.$onInit);
assert.strictEqual(mainControllerInstance.$scope, $scope);
...
```

Comment: Is there something that prevents `initalizePage` from becoming `$onInit`? Because this is what it is for, an idiomatic way to provide initialization logic to controller, it is basically more testable than calling a method from constructor. As for duplicate declaration, not sure what line the error refers to, but notice that controller instance was renamed to `mainControllerInstance` in the code above (it is an object, so it doesn't have to be named with PascalCase).

Comment: No, the dependencies will be ok in constructor too. $onInit is generally seen as a place where initialization happens. Some things (e.g. data bindings) are available there but not available in constructor. But in this particular case it is beneficial because it eliminates the need for trick with `MainController.prototype.initializePage`. There's nothing wrong with `describe` line. Most likely there are problems with source maps and the location of the error is not shown correctly.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep looking into it! I kept editing comments at the worst possible time, sorry this is jumbled.

Comment: I'm using $onInit now. So there's no way to test the services are being passed to the classes constructor? Also.. `import { MainController } from './main.controller.js';` is throwing a `Can't find variable: require` error. I added a revision to my post if you want to see if it's looking better. Thanks again :)

Comment: This depends on how tests are being built and run. The question says nothing on that. If it's Karma, it should be configured properly. For starters, `module(...)` has to be replaced with `angular.mock.module(...)`, because it won't work with CommonJS modules. As for dependencies, they are just assertions on `mainControllerInstance`, I've updated the answer for example.

Comment: Could you please clarify the importance of using prototype here? As I understand it's a way to extend the behavior of the object instance, but I don't see us doing that here.

Comment: initializePage method is defined on MainController.prototype (that's how methods are defined in ES6 classes). So it should be spied there, before the class is instantiated. You can't spy it on mainControllerInstance because constructor was already called at this moment.